# Where to see the region of google cloud firestore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've activated google cloud firestore in my project but unlike with other resources I can't seem to find a way to see in which region it saves the data in, how to find out?

Answer (score 6):

If you're viewing Firestore in the Firebase console, you will see the region at the bottom left of the data tab.  Mine says:

> Cloud Firestore location: nam5 (us-central)

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation [Cloud Firestore Locations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations), the location of the storing is the same from your GCP Project. So, for you to check the location, you just need to access your project settings, to confirm this information.

In addition to that, you can get more information on your Firestore, by accessing the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). Besides that, there is the below documentation, that you can get more information on managing your Firestore via Firebase Console.

- [Manage Cloud Firestore with the Firebase Console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console)

Let me know if the information helped you!